# make buttons to link with hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

My page already has a menu. What I want to do is have three stacked buttons -- disclaimer, about, questions -- on the bottom right of the page, the first two to link to other pages and the third to open a form.

I have spent days trying to figure out how to have the button change color with a hover effect using a second color image (no sprite) and have an active hyperlink, but I'm finding I can't get them to stack and hove and link all at the same time. I tried containing them all in an element and no longer had active link. Would appreciate help.

HTML:

```html
<a style="display:block" href="#/">
    <div id="disclaimer"></div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="#"/>
    <div id="about"></div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="#/">
    <div id="questions"></div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```css
#disclaimer {
   background-image: url('images/disclaimer.png');
   float:right;
   margin-top:200px;
   margin-right:100px;
   height: 38px;
   width: 100px;
}

#disclaimer:hover {
   background-image: url('images/disclaimerh.png');
}

 #about {
    background-image: url('images/about.png');
    float:right;
    height: 38px;
    width: 100px;
 }

#about:hover {
    background-image: url('images/abouth.png');
 }

#questions {
    background-image: url('images/questions.png');
    height: 38px;
    width: 100px;
 }

 #questions:hover {
   background-image: url('images/questionsh.png');
 }
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but my first thought would be to put the :hover on the <a> element instead of the enclosed <div>.

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS tooltip similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/greypants/zgCb7/), but with a custom background image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues here.  First you're using two different HTML tags a link and divisor and you're giving the IDs to the divisor not the links.

Now any code between the starting link tag  and ending link tag  is what is displayed as the link.  So your

```
<div id="disclaimer"></div>
```

is your link.  However a empty divisor doesn't show any visible element.

Therefore to fix your code you need to do few steps:
1: Move the ID from the  to the  in your HTML code.
2: I would modify your CSS code to use the :link element. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp
3: Make sure the href linked is a valid URL of the page you want to link to aka href="index.html"

Besides step here are the first two fixes:

Step 1

```
<a style="display:block" href="#" id="disclaimer" />
<div></div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="#" id="about" />
<div></div>
</a>
<a style="display:block" href="#" id="questions" />
<div></div>
</a>
```

Step 2

```
#disclaimer:link { background-image: url('images/disclaimer.png');
float:right; margin-top:200px; margin-right:100px; height: 38px; 
width: 100px; }
#disclaimer:hover {
background-image: url('images/disclaimerh.png');
}

#about:link {
background-image: url('images/about.png');
float:right;
height: 38px;
width: 100px;
}

#about:hover {
background-image: url('images/abouth.png');
}

#questions:link {
background-image: url('images/questions.png');
height: 38px;
width: 100px;
}

#questions:hover {
background-image: url('images/questionsh.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edward, this helps. Still can't get them to stack, but this gets me much closer!

Comment: I'm unsure of what you mean by get them to stack. Align Vertically like below or what?

Link1
Link2
Link3

Comment: So that the bottom right hand corner is stacked one on top of the other vertically. I finally just compromised and had them horizontally.

Comment: Try adding <br> after each </a> in the HTML code. It adds a line break.

Comment: @EdwardCrader What do you mean by "a divisor in CSS doesn't support the hover element."? divs _do_ support the `:hover` pseudo-class, if that's what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Mr Lister, you're right corrected edited what I meant to say.